# Firebase get document collection based on specific field using angular

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

[image: firebase image]

I want to get collection data based on UserId field .

```
getData(){
   const data$ = this.fbs.collection(this.trackerData,ref=> ref.where('UserId','==',"WrKDk0XSNjU20FI0EVRvADzvNHz1")).snapshotChanges().subscribe(res=>{
     console.log(res);
   });
}
```

if i get data like this i am getting response as :-

[image: response]

but i need response data like :-

[image: actual response]

Comment: The `DocumentSnapshot` objects are in the `payload` property of the result in your first screenshot, so you should be able to get them from there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your stream to get what you want:

```
getData(userId: string){
    return this.fbs.collection(
        this.trackerData,
        ref=> ref.where('UserId','==',userId)
    ).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(action => {
            const data = action.payload.data();
            const id = action.payload.id;
            return { id, ...data };
        })
    );
}

getData("WrKDk0XSNjU20FI0EVRvADzvNHz1").subscribe(res=> console.log(res));
```